# How to display session in listview template

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp:listview layouttemplate sessions doesnt work...

```
<option value="1"<%# Session["fCheck"].Equals("1") ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "" %>>Ano</option>
```

Please can anybody help me how to get session variable to the template?

Comment: ive just kicked it out of the listview

Answer (score 0):

Just try `<%= ... %>`

like this

```
<option value="1" <%= Session["fCheck"].Equals("1") ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "" %>>Ano</option>
```

Note: make sure `Session["fCheck"]` always has some value or add a null check.

Comment: this will trigger error:
"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."

Comment: @haXis it doesn't look like it's a server side control

Comment: forgot to mention its layouttemplate